# Join as per category

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a way to populate missing records as per category in SQL? For example dat2 table is standard table. But category ABC does not have March 9th and similarly BCG does not have March 23.

```
with dat1 as (
select convert(date, DATEADD(day,+14,getdate()), 103)  as [date1], 'ABC' as Fund, 2 as val union 
select convert(date, getdate(), 103)  as [date1], 'BCG' as Fund, 2 as val ),

dat2 as 
(select convert(date, DATEADD(day,+14,getdate()), 103)  as [date] union select convert(date, getdate(), 103)  as [date] )

--select * from dat1
select *  from dat1
full outer join dat2 on [date1] = [date]
```

Output below

```
date1         Fund  val date
2021-03-09     BCG  2   2021-03-09
2021-03-23     ABC  2   2021-03-23
```

Expected output

```
date1         Fund  val date
2021-03-09     BCG  2   2021-03-09
2021-03-23     ABC  2   2021-03-23
2021-03-09     ABC  0   2021-03-09
2021-03-23     BCG  0   2021-03-23
```

Is the possible to achieve?

Comment: I have added the sample data. if you run the above query you will get it

Comment: Why are these values stored in different tables?

Comment: dat2 is a standard table in the db. dat1 is table where we have values. We need to compare dat1 with dat2 as per category in dat1. Makes sense? :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff any more info you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure whether it's the best path to choose but it will do the trick.

> ```
> with dat1 as(
> select convert(date, DATEADD(day,+14,getdate()), 103)  as [date1], 'ABC' as Fund, 2 as val  union 
> select convert(date, getdate(), 103)  as [date1], 'BCG' as Fund, 2 as val ),
>
> dat2 as 
> (select convert(date, DATEADD(day,+14,getdate()), 103)  as [date] union select convert(date, getdate(), 103)  as [date] )
>
> select t.date1,t.fund,coalesce(d.val,0)val,t.date from (select dat1.date1,f.fund,dat1.val ,dat2.date from dat1 
> full outer join dat2 on [date1] = [date]
> ,(select fund from dat1)F)t
> left join dat1 d on t.fund=d.fund and t.date1=d.date1
> order by val desc ,date1
> GO
> ```
>
> | date1 | fund | val | date |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-03-09 | BCG | 2 | 2021-03-09 |
> | 2021-03-23 | ABC | 2 | 2021-03-23 |
> | 2021-03-09 | ABC | 0 | 2021-03-09 |
> | 2021-03-23 | BCG | 0 | 2021-03-23 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6326b4bf4e120d8e35f426e93f07d459)*

Comment: @Vinay prakash Please let me know if you are still facing any more difficulties with this query.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much simpler to visualize with data in *tables*.  But you have the dates in one table and the codes in the other.  Use a `cross join` to generate all the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select d.date, f.fund, coalesce(date1.val, 0) as val
from dat2 d cross join
     (select distinct fund from dat1) f left join
     dat1
     on dat1.date1 = d.date and dat1.fund = f.fund;
```

The second date column is superfluous.